# How would I render a isLoading element in react-native FlatList while it is loading data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am writing a news feed where the `FlatList` is fetching data from the backend in `loadData`, and on finished, `renderItem`. Both the use case and my code is standard. The full code is here: https://gist.github.com/pgbovine/8910348, where in the comments section I provided a use case.

The problem is that it takes a while to fetch the data, and I would like to render a placeholder while the data is loading. Currently `OneFeed` is not visible when the app loads, and when the app does load, it "jumps" into appearance, making everything very jarring.

It's unclear how I would accomplish this ... since I do not control when `OneFeed.rendreItem` actually renders ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  return this.props.getData ? list : null;
```

In here, you can try to render ActivityIndicator like this:

```
  return this.props.getData ? list : <View><ActivityIndicator /></View>;
```

If your ActivitiyIndicator does not show in the center, you can add some styles to the containing View.

---

added later:

One of the common practices I see is that you have loading state set true while fetching data from backend and set it false once it is done. You can refer to the loading state to display ActivityIndicator.

Also, to make the ux of your app better often time it is worth your time to think about what you are going to display in the following scenarios:

- Before loading data.
- While loading data.
- After loading data -- data is empty.
- After loading data -- data is **too many**.
- After loading data -- failed at fetching.

Comment: `this.props.getData` always return true so long as OneFeed passes the function in through props. And doing `this.state.loading ? list : <... />` gets wonky behavior because the screen is constantly `loading` on scroll

Comment: In that case, you can set a new state like `isLoading` and set it true while loading your data and turn it into false once loading is done.

Comment: ok I solved it by showing a landing page until everything is loaded

Answer (score 4):

There is a better way to handle this without unmounting the FlatList component. Use `ListEmptyComponent` of FlatList and control the loading state there.

```
  <FlatList 
    data={[...]}
    renderItem={...}
    ListEmptyComponent={() => {
      return isLaoding ? <ActivityIndicator /> : <EmptyMessageComponent />;
    }}
  />
```

Comment: If `data` has items even while it's loading, but you want to show that a loading state (if the data list is updated only after the loading is completed), then you can use an empty list in the `data` property when `isLoading` is `true`: `data={isLoading ? [] : data}`. It may be useful to give the user a faster feedback.